# Comparing a string against any other variable to determine type in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, variables, comparison, typeof

I am aware of being able to use `typeof`, however, i would like to know if using

```
String(anyVariable) === anyVariable
```

in order to figure out if `anyVariable` is a string:

- Is a generally valid approach?
- Works consistently among browsers?
- Has any pitfalls?

Comment: Why in the world would you do this?  As you already seem to now, use `typeof` if you want to know it it's a string.  What you're trying to do is just more complicated and would perform worse.

Comment: I came up with the idea out of necessity before `typeof` (which i rarely use) came to my mind. I wondered if the first idea was a valid approach and decided to ask.

Comment: So, now that you know about `typeof` why do it the less efficient way vs. the way  that is specified in the language?  Simpler is better unless you have a reason to go more complex.

Comment: Are you sure it would perform worse? Why would it? Please constitute this in an answer, if you can. I'd really like to get down to this. Its all about learning.

Comment: You're calling a constructor and creating a new object and then doing a string comparison just to examine the type.  This will probably invoke at least two instances of memory management and then some garbage collection when all `typeof` needs to do it check a property of the internal javascript object.  I didn't run performance tests, but common sense tells you which is likely to be faster.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/typeof-implement

Comment: @MattiMehtonen - nice.  `typeof` is 15x faster in Chrome.

Comment: Fair enough! But my question being a valid question, why cannot you post that as an answer so i can accept it? Matti: that is perfect! Thanks for showing me this. The difference is almost horrifying!

Comment: typeof is faster even when used against instanceof http://jsperf.com/typeof-function-vs-instanceof/10 .. and for performance this is a interesting article : http://rubyjs.org/blog/2012/12/when-to-use-typeof/

Comment: OK, I turned my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of no reason to use your method vs. the much simpler `typeof`.  Yours is likely to perform worse (15x slower by Matti's jsperf) and be more complex.

Your method is going to require multiple memory manipulations (creating string object, then assign string value to it) and then need to run the garbage collector afterwards whereas `typeof` just looks at a property of the internal javascript object.

When in doubt, choose the simplest method that solves your problem.

When in doubt, choose the method that is specified in the language definition for solving your problem.

When in doubt, choose the method that requires less memory manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

I would say do not do that, and use typeof because "String" is used to manipulate a stored piece of text, not compare types. It is best to use the features in their intended use, to assure the most stability, and best practice out of it. Also, the purpose is to extend the type with methods. So you are basically causing more work and processing, instead of just a type comparison. Hopefully that answers it, though this is a question that merely has an "opinion" as an answer. You wouldn't create a new object, assign it to your current object, to check if it is a type of object would you? No, you would just use "typeof".

Comment: You most beautifully explained why `typeof` the reasonable way to go!

Comment: I also like jfriend00's response, and had to vote it.  Like I said, an open ended answer, but reasonable question. Reminds me kind of those question in .net like, "Why should you use int, instead of Int32". There is a reason for it, but is not, actualy, incorrect either way. only the "best practice".